# Svelte conditional rendering not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, sveltekit

I've got a page on svelte called `login`. Across my webapp I'm displaying a drawer and a header for all pages but I want those not to be shown when accessing `login`. To do so I've added a couple conditions on `+layout.svelte`. It get's the value of the current page from the URL, validates that value against an array of allowed pages and populates a couple of boolean variables to validate whether the header and the drawer should be displayed or not.

```
<script>
    import {page} from '$app/stores';
    import "../app.css";
    import Alert from "../lib/components/Alert.svelte";
    import SidebarMenu from "../lib/layout/SidebarMenu.svelte";
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    let currentPage;
    let visibleDrawer = true;
    let visibleHeader = true;

    const noDrawerPages = [
        "pos",
        "login",
    ];

    const noHeaderPages = [
        "login",
    ];

    /**
     * sveltekit hook that is called whenever there is a navigation event (ie a route is changed).
     */
    onMount(() => {
        visibleDrawer = displayDrawer();
        visibleHeader = displayHeader();

        console.log("displace drawer", visibleDrawer)
        console.log("visible headers", visibleHeader)
    });

    /**
     * Verifies whether the drawer must be visible or not.
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    const displayDrawer = () => {
        const strippedPageName = currentPage.replace("/", "");
        return !noDrawerPages.includes(strippedPageName);
    }

    /**
     * Verifies whether the header must be visible or not.
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    const displayHeader = () => {
        const strippedPageName = currentPage.replace("/", "");
        return !noHeaderPages.includes(strippedPageName);
    }

    /**
     * Reactive elements
     */
    $: currentPage = $page.url.pathname;
    $: showDrawerClass = visibleDrawer ? "drawer lg:drawer-open" : "";

</script>

<div id="app">

    <div class=" { showDrawerClass }" >

        <!-- hidden checkbox to toggle the visibility of the sidebar -->
        <input id="main-drawer" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle"/>
        <!-- All your page content goes here -->
        <div class="drawer-content flex flex-col">


            <div class="text-gray-800 w-full">


                {#if visibleHeader}
                    <div>Header</div>
                {/if}
            </div>

            <!-- Main content -->
            <main class="items-center min-h-screen justify-center w-full pt-12 p-12 border-accent-content/5 bg-gray-100">
                <Alert />
                <slot/>
            </main>

        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar menu -->
        {#if visibleDrawer}
        <SidebarMenu />
            {/if}

    </div>

</div>
```

Now, the issue is the following. When the `login` page is loaded, both the header and the drawer are visible for a moment and then they disappear. What's going on? why are they being displayed at all? when rendering, it checks for the value of `visibleDrawer` and `visibleHeader`, after getting both values then if they are `false` their content should not be rendered at all, isn't that right? what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

onMount is only executed in the client (it is not evaluated server side). In addition, it is executed only after the component has been mounted to the DOM. The doc says:

> The onMount function schedules a callback to run as soon as the component has been mounted to the DOM. [...] onMount does not run inside a server-side component.

Because your variables are initialized with `true`, it is logic that you see your header and your drawer appear (when the component is mounted) and then disappear (when the onMount function is executed).

Try with a reactive block instead of onMount:

```js
$: currentPage, {
  visibleDrawer = displayDrawer();
  visibleHeader = displayHeader();
}
```

The doc says that `$page` is only available during component initialization on the server but it seems to work in a  reactive block.